# Display a date minus 2 days

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I display a date from a ACF custom field like this:

```
<?php echo date('j F Y',strtotime(get_sub_field('date') ) ) ; ?>
```

How would I display the date two days earlier?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `date('j F Y',(strtotime ( '-2 days' , strtotime ( get_sub_field('date')) ) ));` should work